# SQL get the next rows value into current row

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the next row's 'alignment' value and store it into the current row in a field called nextAlign. I have tried using grouping and also the unique identifier for this table is not consistent and doesn't always  have an increment of 1. Here is some data:

```
 type        field                        starttop startleft  length  decimals alignment
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Text      CUSTOMER DETAILS CONFIRMATION      13.00     38.00     30.00     0.00      Centre
Text      Please spare a few minutes to      15.00     2.00      30.00     0.00      Left          
Text      confirm your details as held       15.00     2.00      30.00     0.00      Wrap      
Text      on our system. You may fax the     15.00     2.00      30.00     0.00      Wrap      
Text      form to the number above.          15.00     2.00      30.00     0.00      Wrap      
Text      Any information you may supply     17.00     2.00      30.00     0.00      Left          
Text      will not be made available to      17.00     2.00      30.00     0.00      Wrap      
Text      third parties according to the     17.00     2.00      30.00     0.00      Wrap      
Text      Privacy Act.                       17.00     2.00      30.00     0.00      Wrap      
Text      Legal name:                        20.50     2.00      30.00     0.00      Left
```

All I want is a column called 'nextAlign' that has the following data:

```
nextAlign

-Left
-Wrap
-Wrap 
-Wrap
-Left
-Wrap
```

Comment: How do you define the "next" alignment? Which column can be used for sorting? starttop?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify your DBMS, so this is ANSI SQL:

```
select type, 
       field, 
       align, 
       lead(align) over (order by starttop) as next_align,
       starttop,
       startleft
from the_table
```

Comment: I dont think the lead function is available for this DBMS. I think Microsoft is only just releasing it for 2012 version.

Comment: @user1805691: "SQL Server Management Studio 2008" is a client tool. It doesn't say anything about the version of the SQL Server you are connecting to. But yes, it is only SQL Server 2012 where they added full support for windowing functions.

Comment: Sorry, we are running SQL Server 2008. Is there a work around for the lead function then?

Comment: @user1805691: look at tr3's or Zsolt Botykai's answers. It won't be terribly fast, but doable.

Answer (score 0):

use ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY )

and outer join it to the same select this way: select_1_rownumber = select_2_rownumber+1

Comment: No need for row_number() if you have a modern DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

```
with temptable as 
( select rownum
         ,type 
         ,field 
         ,starttop 
         ,startleft 
         ,length 
         ,decimals 
         ,alignment 
    from YOURTABLE )
select   t.type 
         ,t.field 
         ,t.starttop 
         ,t.startleft 
         ,t.length 
         ,t.decimals 
         ,t.alignment
         ( select tt.alignment from temptable tt where tt.rownum = t.rownum+1 ) nextalign
    from temptable t
```

Might work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're logic is very helpful but I have tried your answer and it is still not pointing to the next records. I have even done it the long way of having two tables with a union and it still isnt correct.